# Single colorkey for raster and points Levelplot R

Tags: r, maps, raster, geopoints, levelplot

Using the sample data below, how can I generate rasters and spatial points plot with the same colorkey as in the "manually" joined plot shown below?

```
library(rasterVis)
library(raster)
library(colorRamps)
col=colorRampPalette(matlab.like2(255))

s <- stack(replicate(2, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))
xy <- data.frame(coordinates(sampleRandom(s, 10, sp=TRUE)),
                 z1=runif(10), z2=runif(10))

levelplot(s, margin=FALSE, at=seq(0, 1, 0.05),col.regions=col)
x=xy$x;y=xy$y;z=xy$z1

levelplot(z ~ x + y,contour=F, panel = panel.levelplot.points, 
          margin=FALSE,col.regions=col,
          par.settings=list(axis.line=list(lwd=3), strip.border=list(lwd=3)),
         cex=1.4, scales=list(x=list(cex=1.7),y=list(cex=1.7)),xlab=list(label="Longitude",cex=2),
          ylab=list(label="Latitude",cex=2))
```

[image: sample plot]

Thanks to @fdestch I was able to generate the following plot using:

```
latticeCombineGrid(mget(rep("pp", 24)), layout = c(3, 8))
```

following my comments on printing multiple plots with the same colorkey.

An issue that remains to be clarified:

1) How can one decide on the order of panels? That is, which row & column to place a particular plot just as in `levelplot` using `index.cond`.

[image]

Comment: Please, post a different question for the last issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should probably make sure that the breaks in the points plot are identical with those defined in the first `levelplot`.

```
## raster plot with colorkey disabled
pr <- levelplot(s, margin = FALSE, at = seq(0, 1, 0.05), col.regions = col, 
                colorkey = FALSE, xlab = list("Longitude", col = "transparent"))

## points plot 
pp <- levelplot(z ~ x + y, panel = panel.levelplot.points, cex = 1.4, 
                contour = FALSE, margin = FALSE, col.regions = col, 
                colorkey = list(at = seq(0, 1, .05), width = .6, height = .6),
                xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude")
```

Please note the definition of a transparent `xlab` when creating the raster plot. This little workaround comes in quite handy when using `downViewport` later on to ensure that the actual plot boundaries of `pr` and `pp` overlap (feel free to run `grid.rect()` right after `print(pr, newpage = FALSE)` to see what I mean).

The actual plot arrangement can then easily be achieved by using viewports from the **grid** package.

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)

## initialize new grid device
grid.newpage()

## add raster plot
vp1 <- viewport(x = 0, y = 0, width = .5, height = 1, 
                just = c("left", "bottom"))

pushViewport(vp1)
print(pr, newpage = FALSE)

## add points plot
downViewport(trellis.vpname("page"))

vp2 <- viewport(x = 1, y = 0, width = .75, height = 1, 
                just = c("left", "bottom"))
pushViewport(vp2)
print(pp, newpage = FALSE)
```

[image: arranged_plots]

Comment: very nice solution. Thanks a lot. What if I have 8 rows and 3 columns to display with a single colorkey? Usually I will use `layout=c(3, 8),index.cond=list(c( 1,2,....))` to get my grid. `Viewport` can be tricky for arranging plots. Any work-around for `layout` and `index.cond`?

Comment: For this particular purpose, there is a function called [`latticeCombineGrid`](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/blob/master/R/latticeCombineGrid.R) in our **Rsenal** package. Simply install the package via `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal")` and run e.g. `latticeCombineGrid(mget(rep("pp", 24)), layout = c(3, 8))`. Note that the results look best when all plots have identical x and y limits.

Comment: you saved my day. `latticeCombineGrid` looks very promising. I will definitely try it out. Thanks again.

Comment: For future reference, `latticeCombineGrid()` has been moved to [Orcs](https://rdrr.io/cran/Orcs/man/latticeCombineGrid.html).

Comment: In above plot, how x and y tick labels can be printed as Geographic coordinates (e.g. 101W, 102W, 15N, etc.)?

Comment: The raster object needs a valid CRS assigned in order to render geographic coordinates correctly. Something like `projection(s) = "+init=epsg:4326"` should do the trick. For the points data, this basically also applies, but the coding involved becomes a little more extensive. I suggest you have a look at `spplot()` or **sf**'s `plot()` method to figure out this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using `latticeExtra::c.trellis`:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

s <- stack(replicate(2, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))
xy <- data.frame(coordinates(sampleRandom(s, 10, sp=TRUE)),
                 z1=runif(10), z2=runif(10))

## Define theme and breaks
myTheme <- BTCTheme()
my.at <- seq(0, 1, 0.05)
```

- Plot the `Raster*` object, using `rasterVis::levelplot`:

  ```
  p1 <- levelplot(s, margin=FALSE,
                      at = my.at,
                      par.settings = myTheme)
  ```
- Plot the points, using `lattice::levelplot`:

  ```
  p2 <- levelplot(z1 ~ x + y, data = xy,
                      at = my.at, 
                      panel = panel.levelplot.points,
                      par.settings = myTheme)
  ```
- Join them with `latticeExtra::c.trellis`:

  ```
  p3 <- c(p1, p2, layout = c(3, 1))
  ```
- Unfortunately, `c.trellis` does not assign the strip labels correctly, so you have to define them directly:

  ```
  update(p3,
      strip = strip.custom(factor.levels = c(names(s), "Points")))
  ```

[image: raster + points]

Comment: this is even more straightforward and easy to implement. Thanks. The last line of code can be used to decide where each plot is placed in the panel. If I know the names of `s` then I can easily decide on the order in which to display them.